# ADFS - Federation Metadata XML - how often is this read by the relying party?

Tags: adfs

Can't find information on this in the MS documentation but my feeling is that the federation metadata xml containing the public key for token signatures is read once per login.

Or could it be on every request?

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's part of the Startup class as it needs to be called very infrequently.

Certificates could be valid for years so no need to call often.